# Angular 8 href redirection

Tags: angular, routes, href

I have an angular application. I have following code inside my one of component

```
<a [href]="element.upload_cv" target="_blank">{{element.upload_cv}}</a>
```

`element.upload_cv` is an URL like `https://www.google.net`

I build the application using `ng build --baseHref=/dashboard/ --prod`. When `--baseHref` is set the `href` redirection is not happening properly. It appends `https://www.exmaple.org/dashboard/` to the absolute URL like follows

```
https://www.example.org/dashboard/www.google.net
```

I want absolute redirection URL like

```
https://www.google.net
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

HTML:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" (click)="openUrl(element.upload_cv)">{{element.upload_cv}}</a>
```

Create a function like this:

```
 openUrl(url: string) {
    if (url != "" && url != undefined) {
        window.open(url, "_blank");  
    }    
  }
```

Comment: It still appends `https://www.example.org/dashboard` to the URL. It has something to do with prod build. It works fine locally. But in production with `--baseHref` set, it does not work like expected. Thanks for the effort